# How would I change language of days of week in php?

Tags: php

I am looking for a simple way to change the language of the days of the week. I use the simple code below to call out the current day Monday, Tuesday, but I need it in French, and I've tried setting locale etc but this is not working for me.
I think arrays would do the job, but again, I could not get it to work with my limited knowledge.

```
<?php echo date('l'); ?>
```

Comment: IMO you need a mapping array, array("Monday" => "Monday in French", etc) plus conditional logic

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strftime()` function for this - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php. `date()` is not locale dependent.

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
echo strftime(" in French %A and");
```

[for more info click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: Thanks I managed to use
<?php setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR"); echo strftime("%A"); ?>
Successfully, although not sure how to have the first letter capitalized?

Comment: use ucword(), it will do that for you